# My function call the return before the rest of the code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I am trying to loop through the list of classes see if there is a match or not
if there is a match return a `Response` and say there is a match
otherwise register the student

I am using `django` and `django-restframework`

Here is my code

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,])
def createOrderForOnlineClasses(request):
    user = request.user
    data = request.data
    Class = OnlineClass.objects.get(id= data["classId"])

    orderCred = {
        'pin' : 'SOME_PIN',
        'amount' : int(Class.totalPrice),
        'callback' : 'http://localhost:3000/verify/',   
    }
   
    for i in user.userprofile.onlineClass.all():
        if i.id == Class.id:
            return Response({"details": "Already registered"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        try:
            response = requests.post("https://panel.aqayepardakht.ir/api/create", data=orderCred)
            if response.status_code == 200 and not response.text.replace('-',"").isdigit():
                # url ='https://panel.aqayepardakht.ir/startpay/'+response.text
                registeredClass = RegisterStudentForOnlineClass.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    totalPrice = int(Class.totalPrice),
                    transId = response.text,
                    onlineClassName= Class
                )
                serializer = RegisterForClassSerializer(registeredClass , many=False)
                print(serializer.data)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response({"details": "Error"} , status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({"details": f"{e}"})
    return Response({"details":f"{Class}"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So the problem is the function call the

```
return Response({"details":f"{Class}"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

first and the rest wont work

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean the last line is executed first in the function? very unlikely.

Comment: Would you mind adding the content of "response"? I think it would help in the search for an answer! However, are you sure `user.userprofile.onlineClass.all()` contains anything at all? If it's an empty object the function would jump straight to the end.

Comment: @LucasGarcíadeViedmaPérez its empty when they register

Comment: Well, then you'll need to add something that states what needs to be done in that case. Otherwise, whenever the `user.userprofile.onlineClass.all()` object is empty, the function will just jump to the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I Have found the answer the thing is all you have to do is first check if the

```
len(user.userporfile.onlineClass.all()) == 0
```

If it is do the rest

else run the for loop